# Как отключить загрузку видео с сервера на мобильных устройствах?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Всем привет

**Проблема**: На странице есть такой блок:

```
<video autoplay id="bgvid" poster="img/water-on-glass.jpg">
      <source src="videos/medoff-video.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source src="videos/medoff-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

Видео работает на декстопе, но при разрешении меньше, чем 1024px его быть не должно И грузится не должно. Я давал display:none, видео пропадает, но в Network файл видео все равно тащится с сервера 
**Вопрос**: Как сделать так, что бы на мобильных устройствах видео на загружалось с сервера?

Comment: А как воспроизводится видео?

Comment: Как вариант: на страницах сайта размещаете просто ссылки. После загрузки страницы запускается скрипт на js, который преобразует эти ссылки в отображаемое видео. В скрипте задаете любые условия.

Comment: @Mihanik71 Обновил ответ

Comment: @Visman это что то очень умное. Можно пример?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавление видео на страницу вынести в JS. Для этого в HTML создаёте контейнет к примеру

```
<div id="video-container"></div>
```

А после загрузки страницы проверяете ширину экрана и если всё хорошо, то добавляете видео

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        if(window.innerWidth >= 1024)
        document.getElementById('video-container').innerHTML = '<video autoplay id="bgvid" poster="img/water-on-glass.jpg"><source src="videos/medoff-video.webm" type="video/webm"><source src="videos/medoff-video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>'
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Все равно вижу в Нэтворке загрузку видео(

Comment: А Вы блок видео старый удалили?

Comment: Неправильно написал условие) Спасибо вам большое!